# flexbox items not centering on second line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am making a responsive page with a series of images.

I want them to be displayed in rows which are centered horizontally. The images in the top row do exactly that, but the images that flow into the second row are not centered. they are aligned to the left of the page.

here is my CSS:

```
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-item {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 130px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  line-height: 130px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="flex-container">
<li class=flex-item"><img src="img1" alt="1"></li>
<li class=flex-item"><img src="img2" alt="2"></li>
<li class=flex-item"><img src="img3" alt="3"></li>
<li class=flex-item"><img src="img4" alt="4"></li>
<li class=flex-item"><img src="img5" alt="5"></li>
<li class=flex-item"><img src="img6" alt="6"></li>
<li class=flex-item"><img src="img7" alt="7"></li>
<li class=flex-item"><img src="img8" alt="8"></li>
<li class=flex-item"><img src="img9" alt="9"></li>
</ul>
```

The `justify-content: center;` only works on the top row.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are missing `"` at the start of class name in `li` tags

Comment: Once you fix your classes, it works fine: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZrVjvp

Comment: @SanchitPatiyal the " was in the actual page but i missed it in the question. It did not work with the " included but i have solved it now :-)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

OK fixed it by changing CSS to;

```
.flex-item {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 130px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  line-height: 130px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  }
```

Comment: the CSS of the OP is just fine

Comment: @fcalderan No it isn't. It only centers on the second row after making the changes to the CSS in my answer. :-)